# Is there a way to force windows to produce short reads/writes on socket calls?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winapi, winsockets

this is for debugging purposes.
To test that short send/short recv handling part of the code is working...
Is there a way to force Windows to produce short send/rcvs even for small number of bytes to be read/written from/to socket?
I prefer to do this per process, but if this cant be done per process Im ready to test how Firefox/ Outlook code handles this also. :)

Ofc I know I can manually add the huge msg to force this, but Im working on huge old code base  that has layers of stuff so even adding a simple huge msg that is filled with random bytes is nontrivial. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can change the size of the internal buffers used by `recv()` and `send()` by using [`setsockopt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the flag `SO_RCVBUF` for the `recv()` buffer and with the flag `SO_SNDBUF` for the `send()` one.

You can find an example [here](http://www.ccplusplus.com/2011/09/setsockopt-example-c-code.html).

**EDIT :** You may want to disable the Nagle's algorithm. In this case, take a look at the *mark*'s anwser.

**EDIT2 :** Like *alk* said in comment, it is important to change the buffers size before any call to`accept()` or `connect()`.

Comment: I feel it is notable that changing the socket's buffers size shall be applied prior to any call to `connect()` or `accept()` to take effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you're controlling the send-side as well, you could disable Nagle's algorithm and send whatever sizes you wanted (without write accumulation)...

```
int flag = 1;
setsockopt( handle, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *)&flag, sizeof(int) );
```